# Is there any other way to extract pairs of elements from the array?

Tags: java

I'am thinking about extract pairs of elements from ArrayList

for example, ArrayList's value is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 . . . 100] and I should make pairs of it.

Simple way is to make sequentially (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) ..(1, 100) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) . . ..(99, 100)

However, if there are 50000 elements in the array, It takes so long time.

I wonder if there's any special way.

Comment: Run it in parallel? What kind of magic spell are you looking for?

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: You can calculate how many pairs you will get from a list on `N` values. For `N = 100`, you get 99 pairs starting with 1, 98 pairs starting with 2, ..., 1 pair starting with 99, i.e. you get `99 + 98 + ... + 1 = 99 * ( (99+1) / 2 ) = 4,950` pairs, aka `N * (N-1) / 2` pairs. So, for `N = 50000` you will get **1,249,975,000** pairs, i.e. more than **1 billion** pairs. That will take time to build, and will likely make you run out of memory. Re-think what you're doing. What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

The space and time complexity of your problem is O(n<sup>2</sup>), which means any solution will be slow, however you may find you don’t need to actually *create* all the pairs, but rather *return* the pair for a given index.

Perhaps something like:

```
private int[] numbers;  // initialised elsewhere
int[] pair(int n) {
    return new int[]{numbers[n / numbers.length, numbers[n % numbers.length]};
}
```